# Как исправить мой косяк с owl carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется слайдер в нём 6 картинок. При уменьшении размера экрана их становиться 6-4-3-1, но у меня появился косяк который я не могу исправить.

Поподробнее на видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xEViU09mOoU

```js
$(".slider").owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  responsive: {
    992: {
      items: 6,
    },

    768: {
      items: 4,
    },

    480: {
      items: 3,
    },

    0: {
      items: 1,
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.partners {
  min-height: 170px;
  padding: 32px 0;
}
.slider {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}
.item {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.item img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.owlcarousel/1.31/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.owlcarousel/1.31/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<section class="partners">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="slider">
          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://s013.radikal.ru/i323/1608/de/2235867e2139.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://s017.radikal.ru/i433/1608/27/f64bc5b5e594.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://s014.radikal.ru/i328/1608/bc/691684d266da.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://s013.radikal.ru/i323/1608/de/2235867e2139.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://s002.radikal.ru/i198/1608/70/c6f8756ad686.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://s013.radikal.ru/i323/1608/de/2235867e2139.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://s017.radikal.ru/i433/1608/27/f64bc5b5e594.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://s014.radikal.ru/i328/1608/bc/691684d266da.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://s013.radikal.ru/i323/1608/de/2235867e2139.png" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, опишите словами, в чем именно косяк?

Comment: Словами? Когда из 6 картинок остаётся одна. Она становиться огромная. Не  понимаю как это исправить. Почему она такая огромная?

Comment: Потому что по умолчанию она растягивается на 100% ширины. Чтобы исправить это, Надо использовать свойство [`itemsScaleUp: true`](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/scaleup.html).

Comment: Что-то я не догоняю куда его нужно вставить
 $(".slider").owlCarousel({
  loop:true,
  
  responsive : { 
   992 : {
     itemsScaleUp:false,
     items: 6,
   },

   768 : {
    itemsScaleUp:false,
     items: 4,
   },

    480 : {
     itemsScaleUp:false,
     items: 3,
   },

    0 : {
     itemsScaleUp:false,
     items: 1,
   }
  }
 });

Comment: В блок с 0. Значение `true`.

Comment: Пробовал не помогло http://s008.radikal.ru/i305/1608/0b/10516d9c04b3.jpg

Comment: А метатег `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` прописан? И вы точно все стили для картинки скинули внутри слайдера? Какую версию Owl Carousel используете?

Comment: Использовал owl carousel 2 решил обновить. Вот результат: http://s017.radikal.ru/i441/1608/fb/6b1d655ccec5.jpg

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, вам придется использовать `@media` для исправления стилей картинки на этом разрешении экрана.

Добавьте это в свой css файл:

```
@media (max-width: 479px) {
  .owl-carousel .owl-item img {
    width: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
```

Своих настроек слайдера вам менять не нужно.